# Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library

Tags: python, oracle11g, sqlalchemy, cx-oracle

I am trying to run a simple query on an Oracle DB using cx_Oracle. My DB version is 11.2.

```
con_string = "oracle+cx_oracle://{0}:{1}@{2}/{3}".format(self._dbconfig['username'],
self._dbconfig['password'], self._dbconfig['host'],
                         self._dbconfig['dbname'])

self._dbengine = create_engine(con_string, echo=True)
print self._dbengine.execute("SELECT * FROM DUAL")
```

I am able to connect to the Database, but unable to query the DB. I keep on getting the following error:

sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError: (cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". See https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#linux for help (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/4xp6)

My LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable has been set and it displays the following result:

/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/lib:

I have followed the link provided but have been unsuccesful yet. It would be great if someone could provide me with an insight into this.

I ran the command : /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/lib/libclntsh.so

And this is my response:

```
 linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffce59d0000)
    libnnz11.so => /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/lib/libnnz11.so (0x00007f992d0a4000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f992cea0000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f992cb02000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f992c8e3000)
    libnsl.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl.so.1 (0x00007f992c6c9000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f992c2d8000)
    libaio.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libaio.so.1 (0x00007f992c0d6000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f992fcb7000)
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you using the 64-bit Oracle client? Check that first, if not then that link will tell you how to install it.

Comment: libclntsh.so is core part of Oracle client. When you fail to load this library, you definitely do not connect to the database. The recent oracle_cx driver is quite sophisticated in a way, how it searches for this library. On the other way Oracle makes it quite complicated to load - for example there are circular dependencies between libs it depends on.

Comment: Try running `ldd /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/lib/libclntsh.so'. That may help you further. If you can build cx_Oracle 8 yourself (from GitHub master) you can set DPI_DEBUG_LEVEL to the value 64 and that will show you additional information that may be of help.

Comment: @AnthonyTuininga What is thi command used to show. it does list  a number of libraries, I'm not sure how will this be helpful though.

Comment: It shows whether all libraries are found. It should point to the location of the library if it is found or says "not found" if it is not